# How can I pick these columns to form another DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, yahoo

I'm trying to pick the `Adj Close` columns from this list of tickers into a consolidated DataFrame, but I can't get there. I feel that I'm very close, I just wanted to create a script where I can easily get these consolidated DataFrame with just the columns of different DataFrames I want to compare.

Here's the code, and I keep getting just a DataFrame with empty columns. Can anybody help me with this, please?

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

start = dt.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,3,25)

index_df = web.DataReader('PETR4.SA', 'yahoo', start, end)
main_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index_df.index)

tickers = ['PETR4.SA', 'PETR3.SA', 'VALE3.SA', 'GGBR4.SA','^BVSP']

for ticker in tickers:
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    df.rename(columns ={'Adj Close':str(ticker)}, inplace=True)
    main_df.join(df['{}'.format(ticker)])

main_df.head()
```

Comment: Please provide the dataframe structures, and your expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your for loop to something similar to below:

```
for ticker in tickers:
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    main_df[ticker] = df['Adj Close']
```